# Using PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet class to set the parameter values for a SSIS 2012 package in PowerShell

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, powershell-2.0

I am trying to execute a SSIS 2012 package programmatically using PowerShell, and I need to use PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet class to set the values for package and project parameters at run-time.  Does anyone know how to do this in PowerShell?  I found the following post showing how to do that in C# but can't find any way to achieve this in PowerShelll.

[ssisPackage.Execute (false, null, executionParameter) times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761056/ssispackage-execute-false-null-executionparameter-times-out)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the PowerShell code that worked for me:

```
$setValueParameters = New-Object 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo+ExecutionValueParameterSet]';

$executionParameter = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo+ExecutionValueParameterSet';
$executionParameter.ObjectType = 50;
$executionParameter.ParameterName = "SYNCHRONIZED";
$executionParameter.ParameterValue = 1;
$setValueParameters.Add($executionParameter);

$executionIdentifier = $ssisPackage.Execute("true", $null, $setValueParameters);
```

You can configure the rest of the SSIS package by following the instructions in this link: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/ssis-2012-using-powershell-to-configure-package-execution-parameters.html